# Interdependent dropdownlists by Ajax in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dropdownlists (`ddl_customername`), and (`ddl_customercode`).

I have sqldatasource1 `(select customername, customercode from tbl_customers)`

I want to change the `selecteditem` in my `dropdownlists` depending on the selected item of the other using AJAX,

The issue looks very basic but I am not able to implement the structure to achieve that goal. How can I achieve it?

Comment: what have you tried? r u looking for smth like this: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Comment: Similar to that, I have already checked that one, but I am tring to learn ajax, and instead of modifing something else, I want to be able to do what is on my mind.

Comment: post some code that you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/basics/introduction/

Covering the 2 dropdownlist with update panels, and giving triggers to one another solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make a wcf service for your ajax calls. You can get lots of value with wcf and jquery.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call